# Check if have substring in variable - Command in same Line (cmd /c)

Tags: variables, cmd, prompt

I try use this code (work very well):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "WP=(wordA) (wordB) (wordC)" & set "WN=wordBB"
IF NOT "!WP:(%WN%)=!"=="!WP!" (echo found) ELSE (echo Not found)
```

But this not work (for use in vbscript):

```
cmd /v /c "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "WP=(wordA) (wordB) (wordC)" & set "WN=wordBB" & IF NOT "!WP:(%WN%)=!"=="!WP!" (echo found) ELSE (echo Not found)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is a better example in my case:

```
cmd /v:on /c "@echo off & set "WP=(v0) (v2) (v6) (v4)" & (for %a in (v1 v2 v3 v4) do set "WN=%a" & if not \"!WP:(%WN%)=!\"==\"!WP!\" (echo Found %a) else (echo not %a) ) & pause"
```

I need use !WN! variable to search a string in !WP! (I can not use %a directly because !WN! is a filter for other functions ...

What i need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the inner double quotes (`"`) with a backslash (`\`). Please check about escape characters in batch file [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

Except the above syntax `cmd /v [...]` is wrong. `cmd /v:on` will turn on delayed variable expansion and `cmd /v:off` will turn it off. Please type `cmd /?` in a fresh cmd for more information.

So, after these, you have to modified your command, so it will look like this:

```bat
cmd /v:on /c "set \"WP=(wordA) (wordB) (wordC)\" & set \"WN=wordB\" & if not \"!WP:(%WN%)=!\"==\"!WP!\" (echo found) else (echo Not found)"
```

By the way command `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` was removed as it was not needed because in cmd you set delayed variable expansion with `cmd /v:on` as mentioned above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `\ `is not an escape character in `cmd`, [it is the `^`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (also for you, @LotPings)...

Comment: Hello, it looks like there's still something wrong. Regardless of the text in the! WN !, it always results in "Found". Please look at my last issue.